# Control to and from static web page and express

Tags: html, node.js, express

I have set up `Apache` web server to `proxy` `node` applications in a `virtualhost` environment.

I have an `express` application that serves a `static` web page:

```
app.use(express.static('.'))
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug')

function getMySQLConnection() {
        return mysql.createConnection({
          host     : 'localhost',
          user     : 'root',
          password : 'pwd',
          database : 'Persons'
        });
}

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/mainpage.html'));
});

app.get('/OnAcceptTerms', function(req, res) {
   ...
});

app.listen(8066);
```

The `mainpage.html` file is just a page that forces the user to accept terms. There is a `checkbox` that says he accepts terms, and then a `button` becomes active that allows him to proceed.

```
<body onload="disableSubmit()">
 <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" onchange="activateButton(this)">  I Agree Terms & Coditions
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Enter" onclick=window.location.assign('http://www.google.com')>
</center>
```

In the `onclick=` method, **how do I would like to pass control back to** `express` so that

```
app.get('/OnAcceptTerms',
```

code gets executed when the user clicks the button on the static web page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like all you need is to redirect the web browser to `/OnAcceptTerms`. You can [do this with a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link).

```
<form action="/OnAcceptTerms" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="Accept Terms" />
</form>
```

With JavaScript (e.g., in an `onclick` handler) you can simply [set `window.location`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage).

```
window.location.href = '/OnAcceptTerms';
```